# Working with an ObservableCollection based on an Entity Framework one to many property

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, mvvm

Working with WPF in MVVM. I have a ViewModel with a CurrentItem property. This is an Item object which is pulled directly from Entity Framework. Item has a collection of Property objects.

```
public virtual ICollection<Property> Properties { get; set; }
```

In the View, I need users to be able to add and remove objects from this collection. To do that, I need to create an `ObservableCollection<Property>`, which we'll call ItemProperties.

There are various ways to do this. The most obvious is to add a `ObservableCollection<Property>` property on the ViewModel. Then populate this in the constructor, like so:

```
ItemProperties = new ObservableCollection<Property>(CurrentItem.Properties);
```

It's also possible to create an ObservableCollection wrapper that sits over the top of the real collection:

```
public ObservableCollection<Property> ItemProperties
{
    get
    {
        return new ObservableCollection<Property>(CurrentItem.Properties);
    }
    set
    {
        CurrentItem.Properties = value.ToList();
        OnPropertyChanged("ItemProperties");
    }
}
```

Which has its own problems. You can't just `Add()` to this collection, since it'll `get` first, meaning the collection remains unchanged. So you'd either have to spin up a new collection, add to that, and then assign its value to the property or raise the `OnPropertyChanged` event outside the property. Either of which also sounds like a maintenance issue.

Is there a more effective way of doing this, which allows you to access the EF property list directly?

Comment: If you want the user to be able to add and remove it is likely that you do not want to use an observable collection.

Comment: @Chris I was under the impression an ObservableCollection was necessary if I wanted to use two-way binding so that the View responded to the user's actions? A quick test suggests this is the case.

Comment: in order to get the view to respond you need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged which observable collection does by default, a custom control would be required if you went down this route but it would be more suited for your needs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On this you have advantage of decoupling between data layer and Presentation , No need to spin up the collection.

Try a `LoadedEvent` to load data from the server.
Sample event is below

```
 private ObservableCollection<Property> _itemProperties;

    public ObservableCollection<Property> ItemProperties
    {
        get { return _itemProperties; }
        set
        {
            _itemProperties= value;
           RaisePropertyChanged(() => ItemProperties);
        }
    }
```

The loaded event

```
var result= await Task.Run(() => MyBusiness.GetMyData());
//Map to the viewModel if necessary

ItemProperties = result;
```

Add to the collection

```
var isSuccess = await Task.Run(()=>MyBusiness.Insert(x));
if(isSuccess)
{
   ItemProperties.Add(x);
}
```

Comment: This is effectively what I did. I'm just uncomfortable about that fact that you have to Add() to your ViewModel property rather than the original collection itself. It feels fragile.

Answer (score 4):

If you have access to your `DbContext` in your ViewModel class, you can use `DbSet<TEntity>.Local` property which it will give you an `ObservableCollection<TEntity>` that contains all `Unchanged`, `Modified` and `Added` objects that are currently tracked by the `DbContext` for the given `DbSet`, but first you need to filter to load into memory only the `PropertyItems` that belong to your `CurrentItem`.

```
public class YourViewModel
{
    private context=new YourContext();

    public YourViewModel()  
    {
      context.ItemProperties.Where(ip=>ip.ItemId==CurrentItem.Id).Load();
      ItemProperties=context.ItemProperties.Local;
    }

    private ObservableCollection<Property> _itemProperties;

    public ObservableCollection<Property> ItemProperties
    {
        get { return _itemProperties; }
        set
        {
           _itemProperties= value;
           OnPropertyChanged("ItemProperties");
        }
    }

    public void SaveItemProperties()
    {
      context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

To save the changes the only you need to do is create, for example, a [command](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms752308(v=vs.100).aspx) that calls the `SaveItemProperties` method. Also, it could be a good idea disable lazy loading to not load twice the `ItemProperties` related to your `CurrentItem`.

If you need to understand more about how this works you can read this [article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592872.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I don't think creating an ObservableCollection for every get is a good idea. Instead I would cache it in a field. Second, for the cached instance, you will probably want to subscribe to CollectionChanged event in which you will changes will be persisted to the underlying collection.

Answer (score 0):

either way is good. But what you need to do is to define an handler to the event CollectionChanged present in the Observable Collection. Your underlying entity must have a default constructor too. So when the new item will be created in the grid, that event will be raised.

```
_CollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e){if (e.Action == System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove)
        {

        }

        if (e.Action == System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add 
        }
```